# Play Framework - edit Sec-WebSocket-Protocol in Web socket Response Header

Tags: scala, websocket, playframework, akka

Edit the Web socket header response sent from server to client.

I am creating a websocket server application using playframework. Right now the websocket response from the server is 
taken care by Play. Following is the response header,

```
Request Header:
  (UpgradeToWebSocket,),
  (Host,localhost:8083), 
  (Connection,Upgrade), 
  (Upgrade,websocket),
  (Sec-WebSocket-Version,13), 
  (Accept-Encoding,gzip, deflate, br), 
  (Accept-Language,en-US,en;q=0.9),
  (Sec-WebSocket-Key,ZvfzpVo3EX4DFA4BRcgRIA==)

def chatSystem(): WebSocket = WebSocket.acceptOrResult[String, String] { request =>
    Future.successful{
      AuthenticationService.doBasicAuthentication(request.headers) match {
        case Results.Ok => Right(ActorFlow.actorRef { out => ChatServiceActor.props(out) })
        case _ => Left(Unauthorized)
      }
    }
 }
```

I want to validate ***Sec-WebSocket-Protocol*** if it is present in the request header or add the same with value in the server response if it is not present.

Comment: From looking a bit to play source, I don't think that's supposed, I guess you can try to clone the `WebSocket` class and see if you can support that change which doesn't seem straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code:

```
// Defined at http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-4.2.2
val MagicGuid = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"

def websocketAcceptForKey(key: String): String = {
  val sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("sha1")
  val salted = key + MagicGuid
  val hash = sha1.digest(salted.asciiBytes)
  val acceptKey: String = Base64.rfc2045().encodeToString(hash, false)
  acceptKey
}
```

Use it like the following:

```
val wsKey: Optional[HttpHeader] = request.getHeader("Sec-WebSocket-Key")
val wsAccept = if (wsKey.isPresent) Some(RawHeader("Sec-WebSocket-Accept", websocketAcceptForKey(wsKey.get.value()))) else None
```